# move phone number on cv

Tags: moderncv

I wrote my cv at LaTeX and after I made a slight change my phone number section move at the top of the cv even if it was at the same line with the email section before the alternations. I'm new to this so please help me fix it. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}    

\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\moderncvcolor{blue}                    

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}


\begin{document} 

% personal data
\name{\textgreek{Γεώργιος}}{\textgreek{Σέρρας}}


\title{\textgreek{Βιογραφικό σημείωμα}}

\address{\textgreek{Νικηταρά 7, 34002, Βασιλικό, Εύβοια, Ελλάδα}}{}{}

\Mobilefone{+6972504540}

\email{geo.serras@gmail.com}

\makecvtitle

\small{\textgreek{Απόφοιτος του τμήματος χημικών μηχανικών του πανεπιστημίου Πατρών.Με πάθος για την επιστήμη, με πολύ καλή τεχνική ικανότητα και ισχυρές διαπροσωπικές σχέσεις με μεγάλη ευκολία συνύπαρξης σε μια ομάδα }}

%\section{Previous Employment}


\section{\textgreek{Εκπαίδευση}}

\vspace{5pt}

%\subsection{Academic Qualifications}

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{itemize}

    \item{\cventry{2011--2017}{\textgreek{Διπλωματούχος Χημικός Μηχανικός (Βαθμός:6.8/10)}}{\textgreek{Πανεπιστήμιο Πατρών}}{\textgreek{Πάτρα}}{}{}}

        \subsection{\textgreek{Ακαδημαικές Ροές}}
            \begin{itemize}
             \item{\textgreek{Τεχνολογία Πολυμερών}}
             \vspace{2pt}
             \item{\textgreek{Επιστήμη Υλικών}}
            \end{itemize}

        \subsection{\textgreek{Διπλωματική Εργασία}}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item {\textgreek{Σχεδιασμός και μέτρηση Ρεολογικών ιδιοτήτων ενός πολυμερικού υδροπηκτώματος σα πιθανό ενέσιμο φορεά φαρμακευτικής ουσίας(Βαθμός:10/10)}}
            \end{itemize}

        \subsection{\textgreek{Βασικά Μαθήματα}}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item {\textgreek{Τεχνολογία Πολυμερών}}
                \vspace{2pt}
                \item{\textgreek{Βιομηχανικές χημικές τεχνολογίες}}
                \vspace{2pt}
                \item{\textgreek{Γενική και Ανόργανη χημεία}}
                \vspace{2pt}
            \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{2pt}

\section{\textgreek{Επιστημονικές δημοσιεύσεις}}

\vspace{5pt}


[1]Constantinos Tsitsilianis, \textbf{George Serras}, Chia-Hsin Ko, Florian Jung,Christine M. Papadakis,Maria Rikkou-Kalourkoti, Costas S. Patrickios, Ralf Schweins and Christophe Chassenieux,''Thermoresponsive Hydrogels Based on Telechelic Polyelectrolytes:From Dynamic to “Frozen” Networks'',Macromolecules 2018 ,51 ,2169-2179



\section{\textgreek{Τεχνικές και Προσωπικές ικανότητες}}

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item \textbf{\textgreek{Γλώσσες προγραμματισμού:} }
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\textgreek{Βασικές Γνώσεις}:  Matlab, Octave, Fortran 95}
\end{itemize}


\vspace{6pt}

\item \textbf{\textgreek{Γνώσεις βιομηχανικού λογισμικού:}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\textgreek{Καλή Γνώση}:Aspen Hysys}
    \item{\textgreek{Άριστη Γνώση}: MS Office}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{6pt}

\item \textbf{\textgreek{Γενικές Ικανότητες:}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\textgreek{Καλές ικανότητες παρουσίασης}}
    \item{\textgreek{Άριστη συνεργασία σε ομάδα}}
    \item{\textgreek{Γρήγορη εκμάθηση}}
    \item{\textgreek{Iκανότητα συγγράφης οργανωμένων αναφορών}}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{6pt}

\item \textbf{\textgreek{Άλλα:}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\textgreek{Δίπλωμα Οδήγησης(απο το} 2011)}
    \item{\textgreek{Εκπληρωμένες στρατιωτικές υποχρεώσεις}}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{6pt}

\item\textbf{\textgreek{Γλώσσες:}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\textgreek{Ελληνική(Μητρική)}}
    \item{\textgreek{Αγγλικά}(Certificate of Proficiency in English-University of Michigan)}
    \item{\textgreek{Γερμανικά}(Goethe-Zertifikat B2 Zeugnis)}
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\section{\textgreek{Εργασιακή Εμπειρία}}

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\textgreek{Μ.Τ. Α.Τ.Ε.                         (2018--)}}
\begin{itemize}
\item{\textgreek{Υπεύθυνος Μηχανικός έργων(βιολογικοί καθαρισμοί,μονάδες αφαλατώσεων}

\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}







\section{\textgreek{Ενδιαφέροντα-Δραστηριότητες}}

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\textgreek{Μου αρέσουν οι προκλήσεις και γι αυτό τις κυνηγάω σε κάθε μέρος της καθημερινότητάς μου.}}

\vspace{6pt}

\item{\textgreek{Μου αρέσει να γνωρίζω νέο κόσμο.}}

\vspace{6pt}

\item{\textgreek{Μου αρέσει η γυμναστική και να παρακολουθώ ποδόσφαιρο και μπασκετ}}

\end{itemize}

\section{References}

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\textgreek{Δίδονται μετά απο αίτημα.}}

\end{itemize}



% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

want the telephone section to be to the same line with the email

thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  Please edit the code so that it is a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem. As it is, I am getting an error "_Command `\fax` already defined_" (after adding a `\end{document}`).

Comment: Your code isn't complete, please amend it. A workaround could be to put your mobile number in the same environment of `\email` or the opposite.

Comment: @FrancescoBianchi thank you for your reply.here is my whole code(edit the question)

Comment: @Mensch thank you for your edit but when i compile it produces the same..the phone number is above the title.

Comment: Off course it is the same, I only corrected some typos and formatted your code to be preinted as code ... Your code has a lot of errors, for example `\small` is a switch and does not expect an parameter (so your code `\small{some text}` is not working, use `\small some text \normal` instead ...). Can you omit `\textgreek{...}` by using encoding utf8 instead (sorry, I do not speak greek)? Do not use `\item{\cventry{2011--2017}`: first: `\item` does not expect an parameter as you wrote and second: Do not use `\item` in front of `\cventry` ... Please correct the errors and repost the new code.